# single parameter string being seen as multiple parameters c# QueryHelpers

Tags: c#, redirect

Here is the original link:

```
https://localhost:5001/Curriculum/Schedule/Event/EventCreate?initialDate=2020-09-04&courseId=1
```

Below is the process to contruct the link redirect.  AddQueryString is a StringExtensions class using QueryHelpers.

```
string passportUrl = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(localUrl)
            ? PassportOptions.PassportUrl
            : PassportOptions.PassportUrl.AddQueryString("ReturnUrl", localUrl);
```

StringExtensions class:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string AddQueryString(this string uri, string name, string value)
    {
        if(uri == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));
        return QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(uri, name, value);
    }
}
```

Which redirects to:

```
https://loginlink/login.page?service=https://localhost:5001/account/login&ReturnUrl=%2FCurriculum%2FSchedule%2FEvent%2FEventCreate%3FinitialDate%3D2020-09-04%26courseId%3D1"
```

The issue happens at the /account/login method.  returnUrl becomes this string:

```
"/Curriculum/Schedule/Event/EventCreate?initialDate=2020-09-04"
```

I added a courseId parameter to the /account/login parameters for investigation and low and behold the courseId parameter becomes set.
How could I reconstruct the ReturnUrl so the Login method sees it as one string parameter rather than multiple parameters?

Edit to answer question -
Login method that gets returnUrl string "/Curriculum/Schedule/Event/EventCreate?initialDate=2020-09-04".  When int courseId is added to parameters, courseId is set to whatever courseId was in the redirect url.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
  {
    
  }
```

Other thing to note: the IHttpContextAccessor Request QueryString is this (ticketvalue is whatever that equals).

```
{?ticket=ticketvalue&ReturnUrl=/Curriculum/Schedule/Event/EventCreate?initialDate=2020-09-04&courseId=1}
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates the problematic string? Is it using [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)?

Comment: It's just a Task<IActionResult> called Login.  What the method does is irrelevant - it is the returnUrl parameter that is not including the full returnUrl.  The returnUrl is being evaluated as returnUrl and other parameters after the ampersand.

Comment: I'm talking about the `AddQueryString` method that adds the `"ReturnUrl"` to the Url. Have you tried `.AddQueryString("ReturnUrl", Server.UrlEncode(localUrl));`

Comment: I added this to the explaination.  This was the code use to construct the redirect URL.  I do not know why the redirect is sending the service returnUrl back as multiple parameters.
Also, I have no idea what you mean by Server.UrlEncode.  Care to expound on what that it?

Comment: There's a link in my first comment

Comment: System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode worked for this.  Server didn't exist and lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Rufus L said, System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(localUrl) is the answer to solving this.